# Delete or hide parent class method C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a chain of inheritance that looks like this:

```
class Socket
{
public:
    virtual int Send(Buffer buf);
    virtual int Receive(Buffer& buf, Callback cb);

    bool IsOpen() const;
    void SetKeepAlive(bool keep_alive );
    bool GetKeepAlive() const;
    void SetNoDelay(bool no_delay );
    bool GetNoDelay() const;
    ...
private: 
    int m_fd;
}

class TcpSocket : public Socket
{
public:
    void Connect(Address addr);

    virtual bool IsConnected() const;
};

class WebSocket : public TcpSocket
{
public:
    void Connect(Url url);

    CloseReason GetCloseReason() const;

    bool IsConnected() const override;
    int Send(Buffer buf) override;
    int Receive(Buffer& buf, Callback cb) override;
}
```

My main issue here is that `TcpSocket::Connect(Address)` is `public` but should not be used by users of a `WebSocket`.  I've provided an alternative:  `WebSocket::Connect(Url)`

Is there a way to remove `TcpSocket::Connect(Address)` from the public interface of `WebSocket`?

I think the obvious answer is to use `class WebSocket : private TcpSocket`, but then I need to write a bunch of functions that forward useful things like `IsOpen()` or `GetKeepAlive()`.  Also, it means that when someone adds something useful to `Socket`, I'll need to manually update `WebSocket` to forward the new features.

Comment: _but then I need to write a bunch of functions that forward useful things like IsOpen()_ -> this is simpler via using: `using TcpSocket::GetCloseReason;` although your manual maintenance point still stands.

Comment: Is declaring a private `void Connect(Address addr);` in your `WebSocket`, to shadow parent method, a valid option?

Comment: Shadowing is done by name, so it is already shadowed. Doesn't stop someone casting to `TcpSocket*` though and calling the banned version.

Comment: Don't use derivation here. A websocket connection uses a TCP socket underneath, but that doesn't imply that the TCP socket class should be a baseclass. Use aggregation instead. Consider also sumbmitting your working code to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Aggregation is a good point,  it hides the methods I don't want to forward. But maintaining the forwarding interface is still effort.

Comment: @pptaszni  Declaring `private: void Connect(Address) override;` in `WebSocket` is a fantastic idea.  I think this is the solution.

Comment: This doesn't accomplish anything more than what you already have from shadowing `Connect(Address)` with `Connect(Url)`.

Comment: You should make `WebSocket` to inherit from `Socket` instead. And use composition, so that, `WebSocket` has a `TcpSocket` member. It should give you what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@pptasni has a good comment which yeilds this solution:

If we can make `TcpSocket::Connect(Address)` virtual:

```
class TcpSocket : public Socket
{
public:
    virtual void Connect(Address addr);
};
```

then we can override it with a private method, removing it from `WebSocket`'s public interface.

```
class WebSocket : public TcpSocket
{
public:
    void Connect(Url url);

private:
    void Connect(Address address) override;
};
```

As others have pointed out in comments:  `TcpSocket::Connect(Address)` can still be called by the user by casting our `WebSocket` object to a `TcpSocket`, or by explicitly calling `x.TcpSocket::Connect(addr)`.  I think semantics take care of both of those cases.  People need to explicitly downgrade the object to use functions which don't apply to `WebSocket`.

Maybe this even makes sense for some use cases.  For example, if someone wants to connect to a basic `TCP` service, but send the send a `WebSocket` header over `netcat` connection for troubleshooting, or if someone wants to permanently downgrade their WebSocket after a failed handshake and fall-back on a raw TCP protocol.  In those cases, it's kinda nice that we still have the ability to call `TcpSocket::Connect(Address)` and it's protected by semantics which explain exactly what we are doing.

Comment: If you were to use a `WebSocket *` or `WebSocket &` instead of a `WebSocket`, upcasting won't be of any help since any `Socket` is polymorphic. You still won't be able to call `Connect(Address)`.

Comment: The real issue here is that your design is wrong. If you were to remove the inheritance between `TcpScoket` and `WebSocket` and make `WebSocket` inherit from `Socket` directly instead, it'll solve your issue. Then you just need to add `TcpSocket` member into `WebSocket` and the problem is solved, with an adequate design this time.

Comment: I don't think I understand the idea of aggregating a `TcpSocket` and inheriting from `Socket`.  In the implemntation, a `Socket` will `open()` and own a file-descriptor.  If I own a `TcpSocket` and inherit from `Socket`, I'll have two file-descriptors to manage, and I really only want one bound.  I can understand aggregation xor inheritance, but not both.

Comment: It's because you modified the question and changed the code... But anyway it doesn't change the moon's face. The thing is that `Socket` must provide the required **interface** (only) for both `TcpSocket` and `WebSocket`. Then `WebSocket` does not create any file descriptor at all. It just uses the one of it's `TcpSocket` member.

Comment: To make it simpler, a `TcpSocket` **is** a `Socket`. A `WebSocket` **is** a `Socket` (inheritance is adequate here). But a `WebSocket` **is not** a `TcpSocket`, but it **uses** a `TcpSocket`. You'll see that when you use the proper design, most of the issues will vanish because they weren't actual issues, only issues generated by a wrong design which makes you twist pipes to make things work by force :)

Comment: `Socket` should only provide the interface any `Socket`-derived type must have. But it must not do things that are not on its responsibility. `Socket` should probably be pure virtual (abstract). Only actual sockets (`TcpSocket`, `WebSocket`, etc...) should own your file descriptor, whether directly (`TcpSocket`) or through composition (`WebSocket` which will use the `TcpSocket` one).

Comment: This results in the exact same behavior as the code you have in the question, except it also adds the overhead of `virtual`. Both snippets prevent you from calling `Connect(Address)` directly, and both let you do it through a base class reference for with `x.TcpSocket::Connect(y)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a design issue.

As said in the comments, simply adding `void Connect(Url url);` to the derived class automatically hides the inherited method (unless you explicitly enable it with `using`).

But this doesn't stop the user from coverting the object to `TcpSocket &`, and accessing `Connect(Address addr)` that way. Or simply doing `x.TcpSocket::Connect(y);`.

You should change the inheritance hierarchy. Perhaps move parts of `TcpSocket` to a new `class BasicTcpSocket`, and inherit both `TcpSocket` and `WebSocket` from it.

Comment: If someone wants to `dynamic_cast<TcpSocket*>` to use a TCP interface on a `WebSocket`, that's on them.  I think the semantics implicitly describe the risk in doing that.  I don't need to stop people from doing that,  just discourage it by removing it from the public interface.

Comment: @Stewart This works even without a `dynamic_cast`. You can pass a `WebSocket` to a function accepting `TcpSocket &` without a cast. This is a violation of [L in SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Fareanor in a comment, you need to change your hierarchy to reflect a `WebSocket` *using* a `TcpSocket` rather than *being* one.

This can be done using aggregation rather than inheritance.

```
 class WebSocket : public Socket
 {
    public:
      void Connect(Url url);

      CloseReason GetCloseReason() const;

      bool IsConnected() const override;
      int Send(Buffer buf) override;
      int Receive(Buffer& buf, Callback cb) override;

    private:

        TcpSocket tcp;
 };
```

The constructor(s) of `WebSocket` can initialise `tcp` as needed, and other member functions can call `public` members of the object `tcp`.

This may require some member functions of `WebSocket` to simply be wrappers that perform operations on `tcp`.   The important aspect, however, it that it prevents the user of `WebSocket` from accidentally/inappropriately calling any member functions of `TcpSocket` outside the control of `WebSocket`.